# How to add value to string end positin in php

Tags: php

How to Add suffix value in php string(array).

`$string (to)=> $string1` in for loop

```
<?php

for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
{
  $string[]="value".$i;
}
```

Need array as below :

```
$string1[];

 $string2[];

?>
```

Comment: $string.$i[]="value".$i;  is this you want ?

Comment: Yes Bro.... any idea??

Comment: why do you need this? store all you data in multi-deminsional array instead

Comment: From 5 row 5 colmun table, one submmit

Comment: also it's unclear what you are trying to do here

Comment: show your expected array . @BhoopalanR

Comment: From 5 row 5 column table, on submit to get each row (1st row & column(1-5) )columns sum of all values.

Comment: $string='array';
for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
{
    ${$string.$i}[]="value".$i;
}

print_r($array2);  @BhoopalanR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use like this

```
<?php

$string='array';
for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
{
    ${$string.$i}[]="value".$i;
}

print_r($array2);

?>
```

Comment: glad to help you @BhoopalanR

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<?php


for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
{
    $arrayName = 'string'.$i;
    $$arrayName[]="value".$i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sanan Guliyev

Answer (score 0):

This works for variables but don't know for arrays.

```
for($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    ${'string' . $i} = $i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks moraya.re _/\_, array also working just added "[]" at end " ${$string. $i}[]"

Comment: Glad, I could help. Good to know about array.